# How to change thumbnail image of WooCommerce Additional Variation Images plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I'm using WooCommerce Additional Variation Images to add images to my product variations. It did work properly until my last WooCommerce update.

The plugin only shows small thumbnail images of 100 x 100 pixels, while I didn't configure this size anywhere in my theme. In order to fix the issue, I need to customize the thumbnail size to large (or some other custom image size) of my variation images by using a function. Or is there some other feature in the plugin I don't know about?

Does anyone know what function or snippet I need to use in order to call another image size?

Comment: Since Woocommerce 3.3+ Images settings are now handle in the customizer… Go to apparence > customize, then browse in it your variable product and settings will appear. Your theme need to be compatible with WC version 3.3+. Version 3.3+ is a recent major new release, still with some bugs, a lot of themes and plugins are not compatible yet… My advise: always wait at minima 2 month for a major update, and test it completely on a stage version before.

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec for your quick response! I tried to configure it through apparence > customize, but that didn't work out. Besides the settings didn't even appear. Do you know if there is a way to configure it through a function? Or some other work around? Thanks! :)

Comment: For me version 3.3+ is too young and I can't test the code that I do on it yet… I will start on it soon (in less than one month). So I really don't know for the moment, as this is also related directly to the theme.

Comment: Thanks for the response @LoicTheAztec :)